# Rounded corners container IE6

Tags: css, cross-browser, internet-explorer-6, rounded-corners

I have the following HTML which I'm using to create a rounded container using a left image, a right image, a gradient for the background of the container itself, and a bottom image which in practice is normally a "shadow"

I have the following html, it has inline styles defined because it is being generated from a .NET control but I can check for the browser and output different styles.  This looks perfect in IE 8 and Firefox 3.5 but it looks awful in IE6.

**I need to figure out how to get this looking decent in IE6.**

```
<div style="width: 305px; height: 194px;">
<div style="float: left; display: inline; background-image: url(images/LeftSide.png);
    height: 194px; width: 7px;">
</div>
<div style="float: right; display: inline; background-image: url(images/RightSide.png);
    height: 194px; width: 7px;">
</div>
<div style="padding-top: 5px; background-image: url(images/gradient.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x; width: 291px; height: 194px; margin-left: 7px;">
    <h1> 
        Some text...
    </h1>
</div>
```

```
<div style="background: url('../images/small_shadow.png') no-repeat; width:305px;">&nbsp;</div>
```

You can see an example at https://www.msu.edu/~grossm51/sample/test.html.  Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you describe the exact problem you have? Also, can you post the full HTML sample page? I'd like to see what doctype you are using plus everything around this.

Comment: The problem is that the main portion (the part with the text in it)...  gets rendered below the 2 sides in IE6,  I'll include the full HTML page shortly

Comment: You can see a sample at https://www.msu.edu/~grossm51/sample/test.html

Answer (score 1):

http://www.curvycorners.net/

Maybe, this helps you. Javascript instead images. Works in IE6.

> A free JavaScript library for creating gorgeous rounded corners for
>   HTML block elements i.e. DIVs. Supports anti-aliasing, borders and
>   background images.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution for rounded corners in IE6 (and IE7/8) is [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/).

It's an IE-specific script that implements the CSS standard `border-radius` for older versions of IE.

Answer (score 0):

adding the style attribute

```
 position: absolute;
```

to the left side and gradient portions did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a variation on the IE 6 three-pixel problem with floats:

http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/threepxtest.html

To fix it, try this.  To the left-floating div, add a -3px right margin:

```
margin: 0 -3px 0 0;
```

To the right-floating div, add a -3px left margin:

```
margin: 0 0 0 -3px;
```

Finally, on the content div, erase the margin and width declarations.